# Close OpenXML Document Without Saving

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

From what I understand, when you open, edit, then close an OpenXML document such as an .DOCX file, the revised document is automatically saved. If you change your mind and decide not to save the edits, is there a way to close the document without saving? I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Hah! Good detective work. A question about your Answer, though: Does this work both with or without the using block? Your answer implies "without", but as it's a setting for the Open method I'd think with would also be possible?

Comment: I believe it would work the same with or without a using block. Dispose would be called as usual, but because AutoSave is false, it would not save.

Comment: Without "using" block: document won't be saved and/or autosaved unless Discard() method is called at the end. Even if you explicitly call Save() method, it still won't be saved unless you follow it up with Discard() call. With "using" block: document will be saved at the end of the "suing" block scope even if you specify AutoSave=false, from my experiments it appears that AutoSave does not control what happens to the file at the end of the scope, I think it controls whether the file gets periodically auto-saved in the process of editing, just like it happens in Word itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document has an AutoSave property, which is set to True by default. The Open method can take an OpenSettings object, which can be used to override the default behavior:

```
        Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing

        Dim os As OpenSettings = New OpenSettings()
        os.AutoSave = False
        Dim doc as Doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Path, True, os)
```

In this case, the document will not be saved unless doc.Save is called. doc.Dispose will simply release the resources without the save.

Comment: Old thread, new comment - If you're using a "template" document and then using `.SaveAs(...)` it seems to save the template as well

Comment: My experiments show that OpenSettings.AutoSave has no effect on saving behavior at the end of the document object scope, either with or without "using" block. If "using" block is employed, the document will be forcibly saved at the end of the scope regardless of AutoSave value, if "using" block is not employed, the document will be saved only if Discard() method is explicitly called. I suspect that AutoSave is controlling periodic auto-saving during editing, not auto-saving at the end. Alas, the official SDK documentation does not elaborate on that, and we have to resort to experiments.